# Error al imprimir propiedad de un objeto

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$verduras = array("verdura1"=>"lechuga","verdura2"=>"tomate");
echo " esta es una variable arreglo con propiedades : $verduras[verdura1] ";
echo "<br><br>";
#variable con objeto
$frutas = (object)["fruta1"=>"pera","fruta2"=>"platano"];

echo "es es una variable con objecto la fruta seleccionada : $frutas -> fruta1 <br>" ;
var_dump($verduras);
```

Mi pregunta es porque en la línea `echo "es es una variable con objecto la fruta seleccionada : $frutas -> fruta1<br>" ;` me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in
```

Comment: gracias my love ,eres el mejor , ha sido eso el espacio gracias wapo

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo a la documentación para análisis de variables, debes usar la [sintaxis compleja](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex), es decir, no puedes incluir objetos directamente dentro de una cadena encerrada entre comillas dobles, debes encerrar el valor entre llaves.

```
$verduras = array("verdura1"=>"lechuga","verdura2"=>"tomate");
echo " esta es una variable arreglo con propiedades : $verduras[verdura1] ";
echo "<br><br>";
#variable con objeto
$frutas = (object)["fruta1"=>"pera","fruta2"=>"platano"];

echo "es es una variable con objecto la fruta seleccionada : {$frutas -> fruta1} <br>" ;
var_dump($verduras);
```

**Nota:** Los caracteres `->` en conjunto son un conector y puede haber espacios entre la variable que representa el objeto y sus propiedades o métodos, aunque, por legibilidad, se recomienda que no haya espacios, ejemplo: `$frutas->fruta1`. Lamentablemente, no encontré documentación al respecto.